# Ошибка при выполнении таска в роли postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, ansible

Доброго дня. Не выполняется таск для роли postgresql в Ansible.

main.yml:

```
---
- hosts: database_node
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo

  tasks: 
  - name: add postgresql-9.6 official apt repository
    apt_repository: repo='deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main' state=present

  - name: add trusted key
    apt_key: url=https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc state=present

  - name: install package
    apt: name=postgresql-9.6 update_cache=yes state=installed
```

Ошибка:

```
ERROR! no action detected in task

The error appears to have been in 
'/etc/ansible/roles/k.postgresql/tasks/main.yml': line 2, column 
3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: database_node
^ here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В папке `tasks` внутри роли Ansible ожидает увидеть список тасок.

У вас main.yml – это плейбук. Чтобы получить список тасок, нужно оставить только то, что идет после слова `tasks:`.

Comment: благодарю вас, в который раз выручаете!)